# How to install an older version of Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to install Angular 2 but when I'm run `$ ng new myApp` the version is 4. I searched a lot, but I could not find a way to install only version 2.

Does anyone know how to do it?

**Edit**
the command: 
`ng new MYAPP --ng4=false` It does not work.
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use an old version rather than a newer one?

Comment: angular 4 is nothing much different from angular 2, still the same though most of it

Comment: Well, I am taking a course with Angular 2, I know it is not very different, but in case I find myself with errors I would at least have the same file structure that the teacher uses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use angular 4. it's in a release version now and out of beta.

Please look at the options for `ng new`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new

**If you are on angular cli version earlier that 1.0.0** please use `ng new myApp --ng4=false` with that `--ng4=false` being the default anyway.

**If you are using version 1.0.0** You cannot make angular 2 the default. please look at 1.0.0 [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). In version 1.0.0 The cli was updated to use only angular 4 with generating new project. however, you can change the angular version **manually** in the generated `package.json` to the desired version.

Comment: My connection is slow, I'm trying. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Of course I will, but my connection is slow, still downloading the packages.

Comment: seems like it does not, see my updated answer. I looked at the sourcecode for the cli and concluded the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend using Angular 4 - the differences aren't really significant enough to worry about the differences in versions. In fact, one of the goals of Angular 4 is to allow it to be backwards compatible with Angular 2.

But, I can definitely understand the risk of using a different version from the course as a new learner - you want to minimize differences as much as you possibly can so you can be (relatively) sure that an error is because you did something wrong.

So, with all that, I'd recommend two approaches:

The first (and preferable) approach is to identify the angular CLI version that the teacher is using and install that specific version of the CLI (hopefully, at some point in the course, the teacher shows the package.json so you can see the angular CLI version in use. Then I would install that specific CLI version both globally and then in my project).

The second option would be to update the package.json in your application to match the package.json of the teacher (but without changing the global Angular CLI version). This is slightly more risky, but should still be relatively safe if you ensure that the angular cli version in your project matches that of the teacher.

Note that both options require you to be able to get/view the package.json that your course is using so that you can match version numbers. Without that option, it's just a blind guess if you're actually using the same versions as your course.