# Create a new Angular 2.0 project using Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This might be a dumb question but how can you specify what version of Angular you want when you create a new project using Angular cli? By default now it creates with an Angular 4.0. version

Comment: refer to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172528/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-angular/43172572#43172572

Comment: There has to be at least 4, maybe 5 questions here asking the same exact question. Search must be broken. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `Angular-cli` won't provide generating new projects of `Angular2`. This is their [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5731). And the reason is `Angular 4` is now reachable. But you can still generate `Angular2` projects with old version of `Angular-cli`.

Comment: Given all of the insanity between `-rc.*` versions of Angular 2, upgrading to Angular 4 was painless. I only had to change about 4 files and not significantly. In other news, the APIs are still awful.

Comment: I was trying to do a tutorial about Angular material design in 2.0 for some reason pulling the animation package out caused all kinda of problems.