# Run Ionic 2 with Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

A few days ago I started playing with Ionic 2 and Angular 2, but now when I run "`ionic start myProjectName blank --v2`" it always creates a new project with the v3.0.1 ionic framework. Even if I specify "`--v2`" it uses Ionic 3.0.1 and Angular 4 but I want to use Ionic 2 with angular 2 because I think it is too soon to use Ionic 3 and Angular 4 for production web apps.

Here is my command "$ ionic info" output:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

and my package.json dependencies block:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

[Edit]
I also post the question in the Ionic forum if this cloud help someone else. Thanks very much https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-with-angular2/86072/2.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288435/create-a-new-angular-2-0-project-using-angular-cli/43288477#43288477.

Comment: No need to apologise, your english is fine. Also, there is 'almost' no difference between Angular 2/Ionic 2 vs Angular 4/Ionic 3, there is no reason not to use the latest unless you have components that insists on using the lower version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ionic blog](https://blog.ionic.io/ionic-3-0-has-arrived/)

According to this,

> Using version 2.x of the CLI still requires the `--v2` flag to create an app using the latest version of the framework (3.0.1 currently). If you are using the beta (3.0.0-beta.5 is latest) version of the CLI it does not require any flag and will generate an app using the latest version of the framework (3.0.1).
>
> So creating a new app using latest v2 framework (2.2.0 or 2.3.0 I think) is no longer possible. It's either 1.*.* or 3.0.0 now.

Comment: I understand now. I thought that the `--v2` flag stand for Ionic Framework v2.x.x but I was wrong.

Thanks for share :).

Comment: actually that was true but the meaning has changed after release of ionic3 update

Comment: Just adding to this. Yeah, the `--v2` was originally for the 2.x.x version, but we quickly grew past that. As stated, this will change with the V3 CLI release, but for now, `--v2` mean "Give a project that is NOT V1"

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your `package.json` to older versions

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
  "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
  "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
  "ionic-native": "2.8.1",
  "ionicons": "3.0.0",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
  "zone.js": "0.7.2"
```

},

and then run `>_ npm install`

Comment: I am new in the Ionic universe, but are there others "hidden dependencies" or  “especial configuration files" attached to the `v3.0.1` installed in other files/directory like `/plugins` when the command `>_ ionic start myAppName blank --v2` is run? If all Ionic Framework version dependencies are defined in the `package.json` this would be so cool! Thanks for share :)!