# Angular CLI - depdecies

Tags: angular-cli

I installed `angular cli` and I create new project by `ng new`. Problem is that project is based on `angular 4` and for example `ui-router` is returned error after import module. I would like to bootsrap my project on `angular 2`. Is possible to tell in `ng new` which version will be installed?

Comment: What version of angular cli are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new Angular 2.0 project using Angular CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288435/create-a-new-angular-2-0-project-using-angular-cli)