# Angular-cli 1.0.0 creates project with angular 4 only. How to create angular 2 project with Angular-cli 1.0.0?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I created project with command

```
 ng new <project-name>
```

It got new project created with all dependancies to angular 4. 
I checked help also, with following command

```
ng --help
```

Under 'new' option there is no description about angular version to be used. 
Is there any way to control version(specifically angular ) of new Project created by angular-cli

Comment: Why would you want to create a new app as angular 2? Angular 4 is your best bet if you are just starting from scratch today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a new Angular 2.0 project using Angular CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288435/create-a-new-angular-2-0-project-using-angular-cli)